# password validation - 5 tries

Tags: javascript, html

ok so i did a javaScript page when you click the correct password and you will be transferred to another site. now i need to make it that you can only try 5 times and every time you fail an alert will show you how many time you have. after you will try 5 times and fail you will get a massage every time you try again that says "you cant try again" or something like that. (i do aware that this is an insecure way to apply passwords) thank you very much. (also i need it with plain javaScript)  the code -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var password = ["1234", "abcd", "0000", "1111", "4321"];
    document.getElementById('press').onclick = function () {
        var p = document.getElementById("putPass").value;
        if (password.indexOf(p) > -1) {
            window.open("http://www.walla.com");
        } else {
            alert("try again!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What you're asking is very simple. What have you tried?

Comment: I Agree with @Popnoodles, you cant store your passwords for anyone to see.

Comment: Surely you jest? Login is a solved problem. If you can't do it yourself, use a library.

Comment: Please do this server-side.

Answer (score 1):

```
var badpass_counter = 0;
document.getElementById('press').onclick = function () {
    if (badpass_counter >= 5) {
        alert("sorry, too many failures!");
        return;
    }
    var p = document.getElementById("putPass").value;
    if (password.indexOf(p) > -1) {
        window.open("http://www.walla.com");
    } else {
        alert("try again!");
        badpass_counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie value for counter when a password is sent to server and increment that counter if password fails to match.